CORS Error When Sending POST Request from Client to Express Server
I am getting a CORS error when trying to submit a form from my website to my Express server. Here is the setup and the problem:
Server (Express) Code:
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://www.teckwithfeya.com'
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // Log the received data
  res.send("Form submitted successfully");
});

app.listen(7000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 7000");
});

Client-side JavaScript:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const contactForm = document.getElementById("contactForm");
  contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(contactForm);
    fetch("https://www.teckwithfeya.com/send", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
  });
});

When I submit the form, I get the following CORS error in the browser console:

Access to fetch at 'https://www.teckwithfeya.com/send' from origin 'https://www.teckwithfeya.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have set up CORS on my Express server with cors middleware.
I tried using both fetch with JSON and FormData.

Not sure how this would be cross-origin to begin with, because according to the error message you are making the request from https://www.teckwithfeya.com to https://www.teckwithfeya.com ...?

Have you aliased the remote site using your HOSTS file or something along those lines?  I can't see how that CORS error can happen

Where are the website and the server deployed, on your computer or on the same server?  While your server is listening to 7000, is there any host config or DNS and web server to solve/proxy https://www.teckwithfeya.com to localhost:7000?
